# iOS: How to place a button in Navigation bar parallel to NavigationBar Title?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uinavigationbar

I want to place a button on the same level of Navigation Bar Title.

Like the image below.

Need the solution in swiftui as well.

[image: like this]

Comment: its not a navigationBar, Its tableView header. Navigationbar and tableHeaderView are toggling on scrolling the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing the UIBarButton item? You can place it on navigation bar in the storyboard. You can create it programmatically like below and set it to navigation item of the navigation bar

```
let btn1 = UIButton(type: .custom)
btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), for: .normal)
btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(methodname), for: .touchUpInside)
let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn1)
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item1], animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code if you want to add `Button` in `NavigationBar` using `SwiftUI`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello World!!")
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                   //action
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .center)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                Spacer().frame(width: 10)
                Button(action: {
                    //action
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "link")
                       .frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .center)
                       .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
        )
    }
  }
}
```